# Trouble with array without exactly size in VBS

Tags: arrays, vb.net, vba, dynamic, vbscript

I have stacked with this issue:

I have arrays:

```
weatherList = Array("rainy", "dry") 
cityList = Array("Mumbai", "Delhi", "Goa", "Varanasi")
```

But now I have request to include all cities, not anymore only 4 in array and I don't know how to include them all?

```
tab = "countryMap"
For Each city In cityList
        For Each weather In weatherList
            count = count + 1
            ReDim Preserve commandList(UBound(commandList) + 1)
            commandList(UBound(commandList)) = """" & tabcmdPath & """ export --pagesize a4 --pagelayout landscape """ & workbook & "/" & tab & "?Weather=" & weather & "&Route" & city  & """ --pdf -f """ & workbook & "\" & count & ".pdf"""
            ReDim Preserve fileList(UBound(fileList) + 1)
            fileList(UBound(fileList)) = workbook & "\" & count & ".pdf" 
        Next
 Next
```

Request is to go through each city and list weather and then create it as pdf output. But India has a lot of big cities and I cannot manually define them in array and also sometimes I will have information about weather and other conditions and sometimes not?

Can someone help me with this?

Thanks,
Marija

Answer (score 0):

It really isn't clear what kind of string you are trying to concatenate together. The one provided for *commandList* was malformed. There was also no definition or assignment for *tab* or *count*. At a minimum, it seems that *count* should be incremented in the loop.

This will loop through the combinations, expanding *commandList* and *fileList* on the go. You wiull end up with each array one element too large so the extra is trimmed off.

```
weatherList = Array("rainy", "dry")
cityList = Array("Mumbai", "Delhi", "Goa", "Varanasi")
ReDim commandList(0)
ReDim fileList(0)

For c = LBound(cityList) To UBound(cityList)
    For w = LBound(weatherList) To UBound(weatherList)
        Debug.Print cityList(c) & ":" & weatherList(w)
        'what is COUNT? what is TAB?
        'commandList(UBound(commandList)) = """ & tabcmdPath & """ export --pagesize a4 --pagelayout landscape """ & workbook & "/" & tab & "?Weather=" & weather & "&Route" & city  & """ --pdf -f """ & workbook & "\" & count & ".pdf"""
        'what is COUNT?
        'fileList(UBound(fileList)) = Workbook & "\" & Count & ".pdf"

        ReDim Preserve commandList(UBound(commandList) + 1)
        ReDim Preserve fileList(UBound(fileList) + 1)

    Next w
Next c

ReDim Preserve commandList(UBound(commandList) - 1)
ReDim Preserve fileList(UBound(fileList) - 1)
```

Comment: Hi, well I have workbook on server and need to print it in pdf. This is not all code... Count initially was 0 , also tab is particular part of workbook. I need to go through each city and for each weather conditions to print that inside pdf. Anyway, I will try to modify my script.

Comment: The correct way to create an empty array via ReDim is: ReDim a(-1).

Comment: Thank you, but my question is like how can I iterate if I don't know exactly number of the cities? Today can be 10, tomorrow 20? And I need to print them. How should I define inside array my cityList?      cityList=Array(?)

Comment: That is going to depend on how you plan to 'load' the array of cities. If you are not going to type them in then they must be coming from somewhere. You say that the list of cities is different every day; well... where is the list of cities?

Comment: In that case, yes I have list of the cities - there is about 40 cities that will be shown, not always all of them, but I got your point. I need to enter all of them after all, right? I thought that somehow I can avoid that part. But anyway how to skip case when I don't have some city, I don't wanna print that page in that case?

Answer (score 0):

To build a [cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product):

> That is, for sets A and B, the Cartesian product A × B is the set of
>   all ordered pairs (a, b) where a ∈ A and b ∈ B.

you should **compute** the size of the resulting array (if you really need it). As in:

```
>> w = Split("r d")
>> c = Split("M D G V Z")
>> n = (UBound(w) + 1) * (UBound(c) + 1) - 1
>> ReDim p(n)
>> i = 0
>> For Each ew In w
>>     For Each ec In c
>>         e = Join(Array(i, ew, ec), "-")
>>         WScript.Echo e
>>         p(i) = e
>>         i = i + 1
>>     Next
>> Next
>> WScript.Echo p(UBound(p))
>>
0-r-M
1-r-D
2-r-G
3-r-V
4-r-Z
5-d-M
6-d-D
7-d-G
8-d-V
9-d-Z
9-d-Z
>>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found more flexible solution. I have created xlsx file which will be updated once per week with exactly measured cities. My script will read that xlsx file and pull cities from that. On that way I am avoiding empty printed pdf pages.
Thanks all!